# Slow Intent Broadcasts

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm working on an application that uses Android's `DownloadManager` to download files. In my AndroidManifest.xml I register a receiver to listen for downloads completing like this

```
<receiver android:name=".download.DownloadCompleteBroadcastReceiver"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the broadcast receiver's `onReceive` method, I launch an `IntentService` to perform some post-processing on the downloaded file before it's ready for use. Here's what that code looks like:

```
public class DownloadCompleteBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        final long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1L);

        context.startService(
            new Intent(context, DownloadService.class)
                .putExtra("downloadId", downloadId));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.i("Yo", Log.getStackTraceString(t));
    }
}
```

The DownloadService class looks something like this

```
public class DownloadService  extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Some processing logic
        ...

        // Send processing complete
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.package.DownloadService:PROCESSING_COMPLETE"));
    }
}
```

This service is registered in my `AndroidManifest.xml` like this

```
<service android:name=".download.DownloadService"        android:process=":Downloads"/>
```

Finally, I have an activity that listens for that `PROCESSING_COMPLETE` broadcast. That code looks like this

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // Update some UI
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.package.DownloadService:PROCESSING_COMPLETE"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

And finally, the issues:

1) I am seeing delays (as much as 20 seconds) between when the download manager completes a download and when my registered `BroadcastReceiver` receives the download complete notifications. Is this normal? This issue/question is not as big of a concern as the next two.

2) I am seeing delays (as much as 2 minutes) between when my `BroadcastReceiver` calls `startService()` and when `DownloadService.onCreate()` is called. What's going on here? Sometimes my devices will show an `ANR` dialog asking me to wait for the app or force close it. I know I declared the service to run in a separate process, and there's some lead time to create the process and launch the service, however I'm seeing similar delays in successive runs when the process is already created. Moving `DownloadService` to the default process doesn't appear to improve the load time, however I believe the best practice is to run such a service in it's own process to keep it from being terminated should the app crash.

3) I am seeing delays (as much as 2 minutes) between when the DownloadService sends the `PROCESSING_COMPETE` broadcast and when my activity actually receives it. This is without leaving the activity then coming back (an `onPause()` and `onResume()`cycle), though my code handles unregistering and re-registering. What's going on here? I'm testing on a Galaxy S7 running 6.0. I hardly have any apps installed/running on this device that I could image would be slowing down broadcasts. Another interesting observation is that if I send multiple broadcasts, they're all delivered at the same time after the long delay.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: can you show your code that how you are downloading ? and where you are getting callback after download complete.